# magento switching images on both color and type option

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

Id like for it to switch image only on color option

```
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
    <div class="input-box">

    <label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__($_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_attribute->getLabel())->getData('store_label')); ?></label>

            <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
              </select>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
        var spConfigimages = <?php echo $this->getJsonConfigImages() ?>;

        $j = jQuery.noConflict();

        $j("select.super-attribute-select").change(function(e){
            var id = $j(this).val();
            var atrid = $j(this).attr("id").replace("attribute","");
            var img;
            var options = spConfig.config.attributes[atrid].options;

            options.each(function(e,i){
                if(e.id == id){
//                    console.log(e.products);
                    img = spConfigimages[e.products[0]];
                }
            });

            $j("#image").attr("src",img.main);
            $j("#small").attr("src",img.small);
            $j(".magnifyarea img").attr("src",img.big);

        });



    </script>
```

anyone, please?

Comment: can you show a web link ?

Comment: http://www.mylure.webbite-dev.de/index.php/jerkbait/hk-mamma.html

Comment: add this `if(spConfig.config.attributes[atrid].code=="lure_color")e.preventDefault();` after `var atrid = $j(this).attr("id").replace("attribute","");`

Comment: where should i add that?

Comment: after `var atrid = $j(this).attr("id").replace("attribute","");` line

Comment: now there is no options on dropdowns

Comment: oh I changed it now to what you said but there is no changes, still changes image on type option

Comment: ahh, use this: `if(spConfig.config.attributes[atrid].code!="lure_color")return false;`

Comment: Glad that helps. Posted complete answer, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your jQuery script as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    var id = $j(this).val();
    var atrid = $j(this).attr("id").replace("attribute","");

    //ADD THIS LINE
    if(spConfig.config.attributes[atrid].code!="lure_color")return false;

    var img;
    var options = spConfig.config.attributes[atrid].options;

    ...
});

</script>
```